# Change divs layed out across screen, to divs in slider after screen change

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

Change the layout of my testimonials which are in 3 divs and are spread out the screen in a row, when it's on the desktop view, into all the testimonies as a slider when the screen goes to desktop view.

These are the divs that I mention below:

```html
<div class="testimony">
  <h3 style="font-weight:600">Testimonies</h3>
  <div class="testi-container">
    <div class="comment-1">
      <img
        src=""
        alt=""
        width=""
        height=""
        id="img1"
        style="margin-bottom:15px"
      />
      <p><b>Name:</b> Frank Boterguere</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom:12px">
        <b>Occupation:</b> Publisher, FBoter books
      </p>
      <p style="color: #1388ae; font-style:italic; font-size:14px">
        The guys at privycript really know their stuff,
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-2">
      <img
        src=""
        alt=""
        width=""
        height=""
        id="img2"
        style="margin-bottom:15px"
      />
      <p><b>Name:</b> Frank Boterguere</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom:12px">
        <b>Occupation:</b> Publisher, FBoter books
      </p>
      <p style="color: #1388ae; font-style:italic; font-size:14px">
        The guys at privycript really know their stuff,
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-3">
      <img
        src=""
        alt=""
        width=""
        height=""
        id="img3"
        style="margin-bottom:15px"
      />
      <p><b>Name:</b> Frank Boterguere</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom:12px">
        <b>Occupation:</b> Publisher, FBoter books
      </p>
      <p style="color: #1388ae; font-style:italic; font-size:14px">
        The guys at privycript really know their stuff,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to style them differently depending on the screen resolution?

Comment: yeah. I want the divs to be in slider form when its on 500px or less, in a way that will show just 1 testimony at once, giving you the option to swipe to see the rest.